# serving imgs on secure server via file paths

Tags: image, https, path, unc

I keep getting :

do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?

The site is https:\mydomain.com, the imgs are under \serverShare\imgs. When I right click on the img and see the properties:

file://serverShare/imgs/somefolder/004.jpg

How can I show the imgs without this warning?

Comment: how is your https configured?

Comment: not sure what u mean. if there is a way to do this via https config, please let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using a virtual dir on the web server and using https to get the images.